# pymongo: Error Creating embedded array in an OrderedDict

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

While importing SQL data into mongodb, I have merged few tables as an embedded array but while implementing I get syntactic errors stating 'key errors'. 
Below is my code.

```
import pyodbc, json, collections, pymongo, datetime

arrayCol =[]
mongoConStr = 'localhost:27017'
sqlConStr = 'DRIVER={MSSQL-NC1311};SERVER=tcp:172.16.1.75,1433;DATABASE=devdb;UID=qauser;PWD=devuser'
mongoConnect = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoConStr)
sqlConnect = pyodbc.connect(sqlConStr)
dbo = mongoConnect.eaedw.ctArrayData
sqlCur = sqlConnect.cursor()
sqlCur.execute('''SELECT M.fldUserId ,TRU.intRuleGroupId ,TGM.strGroupName  FROM TBL_USER_MASTER M
        JOIN TBL_RULEGROUP_USER TRU ON M.fldUserId = TRU.intUserId
        JOIN tbl_Group_Master TGM ON TRU.intRuleGroupId = TGM.intGroupId
            ''')
tuples = sqlCur.fetchall()
for tuple in tuples:
    doc = collections.OrderedDict()
    doc['fldUserId'] = tuple.fldUserId
    doc['groups.gid'].append(tuple.intRuleGroupId)
    doc['groups.gname'].append(tuple.strGroupName)
    arrayCol.append(doc)

mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(arrayCol)

sqlCur.close()
mongoConnect.close()
sqlConnect.close()
```

Here, I was trying to create an embedded array name `groups` which will hold `gid` and `groupname` as a sub-doc in the array.
I get error for using `append`, it runs successfully without the embedded array.
Is there any error or mistake with the array definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append to a list that doesn't exist. When you call append on them, doc['groups.gid'] and doc['groups.gname'] have no value. Even once you fix that problem, PyMongo prohibits you from inserting a document with keys like "groups.gid" that include dots. I think you intend to do this:

```
for tuple in tuples:
    doc = collections.OrderedDict()
    doc['fldUserId'] = tuple.fldUserId
    doc['groups'] = collections.OrderedDict([
        ('gid', tuple.intRuleGroupId),
        ('gname', tuple.strGroupName)
    ])
    arrayCol.append(doc)
```

I'm only guessing, based on your question, the schema that you really want to create.